# Name of MDI Parent

Tags: c#, parent, mdi

I don't know if I've made this messy or not......

I have an MDI parent created thus:

```
namespace APRSTW
    {
    static class Program
        {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
            {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new MainAPRSTW()); //<= key call
            }
        }
    }
```

In MainAPRSTW.cs, you find this....

```
namespace APRSTW
    {
    public partial class MainAPRSTW : Form
        {......lots of stuff here, and the MDI parent happens here.......}
```

Now we have the parent MDI form. Next is the class that starts the process of creating the child form.

```
namespace TeleDecoder
    {
    class TDecoder
        {......}
```

A new instance of TDecoder also creates a new instance of the following form

```
namespace ChildNode
    {
    public partial class Node : Form
        {......}
```

with the code

```
      ChildNodeForm = new Node();
      ChildNodeForm.MdiParent = ?????????;
```

The question is, what do I use for "?????????" ?

Or, do I need to make some name changes?

I hope I got this across well.

Chuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do this:

```
Application.Run(new MainAPRSTW());
```

you need to store a reference to that form:

```
public static Form mainForm;//at top of module
mainForm = new MainAPRSTW();
Application.Run(mainForm);
```

and then you can do

```
ChildNodeForm.MdiParent = mainForm;
```

Comment: Thank-you, Mike. One smack of the "Easy Button" in your honor.

Comment: Sorry. I'm just learning how to interact with this site. You should see I marked the answer. Thanks again for your help, Mike.

If you have a moment, I'd appreciate it if you got take a look at my current question....

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11786120/my-mdi-isnt-starting-right