# My MDI isn't starting right

Tags: c#, winforms, mdi

My C# MDI Application starts in program.cs, which looks like this:

```
namespace APRSTW
{
    static class Program
    {
        public static Form parentForm;
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            parentForm = new MainAPRSTW();//<-so I can reference this form as a parent in other .cs files.
            Application.Run(parentForm);
        }
    }
}
```

The constructor for `MainAPRSTW` looks like this:

```
public MainAPRSTW()
{
    frmSplash objfrmSplash = new frmSplash();
    objfrmSplash.ShowDialog();

    //windows init
    InitializeComponent();

    //Initialize the program
    InitProgram();

}//close main
```

I have posted a PNG screen capture of what happens when the program runs at

http://www.Blandranch.net/Files/Capture.PNG (case matters after .net)

You are seeing outlines of the child forms and the holes are text boxes and groups. I never see the parent form.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: as I continue to work on this, I commented-out the form shown event handler for the parent form (not APRSTW form) and the parent form appears. I will keep toying with this, but looks like I may have found the general problem area.

Comment: In the same handler, I just commented out the loop that is the main processing loop so that the program will leave the handler. Now, the parent window is showing and the child windows are showing BUT the child windows are NOT in the parent window.

I am setting the child window location, but I PRESUMED that X and Y were relative to the parent window and not my display.

Comment: Hmmmmm.... what does the "-1" mean at the top of this posting?

Comment: It means some people didn't like your question. Most of the time the reason for a downvote is fairly obvious but I'm not really sure in this case.

Comment: The loop was your first problem (what was it for?) Are you setting the MDI parent on your child forms?

Comment: MainAPRSTW  is run because of the line in Program.cs "Application.Run(new MainAPRSTW); The splash screen comes and goes as expected without any problem. I will see about moving it anyway.

Comment: Since my posting, the code that is supposed to be my main program loop has been identified as the culprit, but I don't know why. In fact, if I comment out just the code that does the read from the network and process the packet, then the splash screen comes and goes, the parent form paints and the children appear. My plan this morning is to move that code under a "go" button, which will get clicked by the user so that it won't run until after everything is done.

Comment: But it has left me wondering, where in the program is such a loop really supposed to be? It appears if I put this code under an event associated with this form, things don't work as they should.

Should I use BackgroundWorker to run this code? Will the system mind having a task in BGW that never stops? So far, my research hasn't turned-up answers for this.

Comment: I also found I was setting the MDIParent wrong. That has been fixed and the child forms are in the right place. If it wouldn't be so much work, I'd probably change some classes to make a larger partial class. This is my first run into a project of this effort, so I'm learning the lessons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think showing the splash screen is the issue. If you tell Application that you are starting with 1 form you can't then jump to another form before the first one is shown. What you should probably do is show your splash screen from Application.Run and then have your splash screen show your MDI form.